# Is it possible to create autorun hybrid CD/DVD on Max OSX Tiger/Leopard?

Tags: macos, dvd, dvd-burning

Excuse me for not quite a programming question, but I need to burn a disc that would be autoplayed both on Windows and OSX. I read somewhere, that OSX disables autoplay feature by default (?) regarding to some security issues or wtf. However, posting the problem here in hope Stackoverflow knows how to hack / enable it.

And yes, I know that:

> For Windows, we can setup Autorun to automatically launch the app and, for Mac, we can use special folder formatting to make it clear what the user should do.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229456/creating-multi-platform-cds-for-software-distributio)

BTW, the content to be played is MM Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enable it. The feature isn't disabled — it isn't there at all. The only way to do it would be to have a program already on the computer to respond to the disk insertion, but that's a chicken-and-egg problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks as if it may be of help to you: [Creating a multiplatform autorun CD](http://research.silmaril.ie/autoruncd/)

UPDATE: After reading it seems that a Mac OS 9 tool was required, which isn't much use nowadays